# Loading Chunk {X} failed Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, netlify

So I have a problem regarding chunk Failed. We have PWA Application with use of Suspense, Lazy, etc and we also use netlify to publish our app. Sometimes, we found that after we updated the app and pushed it to netlify, we got error message `chunk {x} failed` and we thought maybe it was caused by cache (since no chunk with that hash anymore).

I think it has problem with mobile browser because netlify should be revalidate new data right?
I also found a solution here (but it is for ios homescreen)

https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-reload-a-create-react-app-thats-been-added-to-ios-home-screen/3337

Is it the right way to do? Or maybe how we update cache in mobile browser to follow the updated one?

Thank you!

PS.: I have already add retry for lazy load and also handle cases in Error Boundary React